# Negative Value Gamma GLM Inverse Link

Tags: generalized-linear-model, python, optimization, link-function

I want to calculate a log-likelihood score for a gamma glm with inverse link function. The score will be used to find optimal parameters ($\beta$) for the model. I'm fixing the shape parameter and allowing the scale to be predicted by scale = ($X\beta)^{-1}$

In the optimization, nothing is stopping the term $X\beta$ from being negative for some observations, and thus producing a negative scale estimate (outside of the support for the scale parameter). My current solution below is just to take the absolute value, but I'm worried this will potentially derail optimization (by BFGS).

```py
import numpy as np

def gamma_inverse_score(X, y, shape, betas):
    """
    simplified version of negative log likilihood, 
    we hold the shape parameter constant and vary
    the scale parameters

    log-likelihood formula can be found here, use shape, scale
    parameterization
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution
    we are holding shape constant and predicting lambda so
    we can ignore terms without lambda

    X: two dimensional np.ndarray of predictors
    y: two dimensional np.ndarray of response values
    shape: value of the shape parameter used in scoring
    betas: one dimensional nd.array of coefficients
    """
    link = lambda x: 1.0/x
    xb = X @ betas.reshape(-1, 1)
    lam = link(np.maximum(1e-3, np.abs(xb)))
    score_i =  (y / lam) + (shape * np.log(lam))
    return np.mean(score_i)
```

later I'll optimize this function for betas using the following code. It's able to find the correct beta values in this example, but I worry about x values with negative numbers, and sensitivity to bfgs initialization.

```py
from scipy.optimize import fmin_bfgs
from functools import partial

X = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
y = np.array([[1], [2]])

optimal_betas = fmin_bfgs(
    f=partial(gamma_inverse_score, X, y, 1),
    x0=np.ones(X.shape[1]))
print(optimal_betas)
```

What's the best approach to dealing with negative $X\beta$